# sed: Multiple character changes on text found by regex inline in a file

Tags: regex, sed

I want to find specific text areas in a file using a regex. And then, in those areas only, I want to perform multiple changes, namely change everything to lowercase and then remove the the following characters [.,\]. After a lot of trial and error I came up with this:

```
sed -r -E -i '/^(\(#)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+){1}(.)+(\))/s|[\.,/]||g; s|[A-Z]|\L&|g' filename
```

But the changes are applied to the whole file. Any ideas?
In general how can I streamline inline changes, i.e. use the output of the previous change and apply a new one (to possibly feed it to another)? Or is it not how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#foo#\n&\n#g
     s#.*#echo '\''&'\''|sed '\''/^foo$/{s/bar/baz/;s/qwe/rty/g}'\''#e
     s#\n##g' file
```

Surround the require match by newlines gobally throughout each line and throughout the file.

Apply a second sed invocation which completely agree with the match throughout each line and then apply specific or global substitutions against patterns that subsequently match.

Before each line processing is finished, remove the newline scaffolding and print the results.